# When I create a 2D array outside of my constructor, I'm not able to resize it, but when I create one inside of it, I'm not able to access it

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to create a method which will create an object which contains a 2D boolean array, with int parameters as the number of rows and columns. Then inside the class, I have methods that try to grab the length and width of that array. The two ways I tried to solve this problem were:

```
public GameOfLife(int rows, int cols) {
    boolean[][] society = new boolean[rows][cols];
}

public int numberOfRows() {
    return society.length;
}
```

In my tests, this attempt was giving me the error that society cannot be resolved to a variable. Then I tried:

```
private boolean[][] society;

public GameOfLife(int rows, int cols) {
    boolean[][] temp = new boolean[rows][cols];
    society = temp;
}
```

EDIT: Oops, forgot to add my method for numberOfColumns:

```
public int numberOfColumns() {
    return cols;
}
```

But the issue with this one was that it was returning 0 instead of 4 when I tried:

```
@Test
public void FailedTestingRowsAndCols(){
    GameOfLife g1 = new GameOfLife(4,4);

    assertEquals(4, g1.numberOfColumns());
}
```

I'm rather new to this, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I'm not really sure about all the details of where and when variables expire, which is giving me a lot of difficulties. THank you for any help!

Comment: You'll want to read up on Scope in Java.

Comment: What's `numberOfColumns` do? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @CameronLambertus Your said that `g1.numberOfColumns()` is giving you 0 instead of 4. Can you show your codes for the method `numberOfColumns()` ?

Comment: @CameronLambertus From your `numberOfColumns()`, it returns a variable `col` instead of the columns of the array directly. Can you show where did you update `col`? Or did you forgot to update it, hence it is always 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I create a 2D array outside of my constructor, I'm not able to resize it, but when I create one inside of it, I'm not able to access it

Take note that you will never be able to resize an array. An array once created has its size fixed. You are merely assigning your current array to reference to another newly created array (which gives you the illusion that you successfully resized it).

As for your question of not being able to access it is highly likely the variable you created exist within ***different scope***.

You can use the following codes (which is very similar to yours), it works fine for me. Hence I am guessing your error does not actually comes from the code snippet you showed.

```
class TestRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GameOfLife gol = new GameOfLife(5, 3);
        System.out.println(gol.getColumns());
        System.out.println(gol.getRows());      
    }
}

class GameOfLife
{
    private boolean[][] society;

    public GameOfLife(int rows, int cols){
        society = new boolean[rows][cols];
    }

    public int getColumns(){
        return society[0].length;
    }

    public int getRows(){
        return society.length;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with what you have posted so far. The below example works fine for me:

```
public class GameOfLife {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameOfLife g1 = new GameOfLife(4,4);
    System.out.println(g1);
  }

  private boolean[][] society;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("GameOfLife{");
    sb.append("society=").append(society == null ? "null" : Arrays.deepToString(society));
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public GameOfLife(int rows, int cols) {
    boolean[][] temp = new boolean[rows][cols];
    society = temp;
  }
}
```